# dll files not getting committed in github

Tags: asp.net, git

I'm very beginner in using git.
I uploaded my coded to git.But when I do commit, my .dll files are not committing. What might be the reason for this ? did I miss anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the repo up yourself?  If not, there might be a git ignore rule (such as in the .gitignore file) preventing the .dll files from being committed.  If so, it's likely for good reason; it typically isn't a good idea to commit .dll files for a couple of reasons.

First, they are binary files, and often they are rather large relative to the size of code files in a repo.  This can lead to numerous usability problems.  If you really do have a need to store .dll or similar files, you should consider using git LFS to mitigate the impact.

Second, it just generally isn't necessary.  Dependencies can be fetched as part of a build process (using an in-house artifact repository if absolute guarantees of version stability are needed).  Build products can be regenerated after a checkout.  Storing such binaries is basically all cost and no benefit.

But if you still want to commit them:  Well, if there *are* ignore rules, you could remove them (though if the repo is shared this should be a team discussion.  Like I said, the most likely place for them would be .gitignore (which is also stored as part of the commit).

If you think there are no ignore rules, you can verify by running `git status` which will tell you what files git is thinking about in the repo.

If the `.dll` files are in the work tree but are not listed by `git status`, then either they're fully up-to-date and checked in or they have an ignore rule.

If they show up as "untracked files", then you would have to `git add` them before they'd be included in a commit.

If they show up as "new files", they're staged and should be included in a subsequent commit.